# What are some good resources for graphing diode characteristics?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

A big part of my next exam will feature questions about graphing diode characteristics. Questions like the image below or questions where I am given an input signal and have to graph Vout over time type of thing. My question is are there any resources out there to practice these kinds of problems. I know how to use LT spice but I was looking for more of an explanation as well. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What topics does your exam cover? The scope as you have described it is ambiguous since there is an awful lot that might be covered; "that kind of thing" is unhelpful to say the least!

Comment: Diode chapter in sedra & smith has maybe 100 Q of that style, though there are plenty of other good books too